# Twitter4J in android app don't work:TwitterException: 401

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I've got a problem while integrating twitter in my android application while using twitter4j:

This is my code:
------- do auth

```
public void doOauth(){      try {
            String authURL = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.i("OAuthTwitter", authURL);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse(authURL)));
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl(authURL);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   }
```

---- on new intent

```
    @Override   protected void
 onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
                Uri uri = intent.getData();         Log.i(TAG, "uri = "+uri);       if (uri
 != null &&
 uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL))
 {          Log.i("OAuthTwitter : url",
 uri.toString());           String verifier =
 uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
            Log.i("OAuthTwitter : verify",
 verifier);             AccessToken a = new
 AccessToken(consumer.getToken(),
 consumer.getTokenSecret());
            Log.i(TAG, "comsumer.toker =
 "+consumer.getToken() );           Log.i(TAG,
 "comsumer.tokersecret =
 "+consumer.getTokenSecret() );             //
 initialize Twitter4J
                        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,
 CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
                        // create a tweet
                        Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String tweet = "#OAuth working! " +
 d.toLocaleString();
                        // send the tweet
                        try {
                twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
                Log.i(TAG, "sucess !!!!");          } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();            }
                        // feedback for the user...
                        Toast.makeText(this, tweet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      }   }
```

Here is the error message:

```
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056): twitter4j.TwitterException: 401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056): {"request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json","error":"Request token must be exchanged for an access token before use"}
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at twitter4j.http.HttpClient.request(HttpClient.java:318)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at twitter4j.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:66)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at twitter4j.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:97)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at twitter4j.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:428)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at com.vortexsolution.evenko.ShareByTwitter.onNewIntent(ShareByTwitter.java:83)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1119)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2738)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2750)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2758)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3100(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2080)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 09:26:34.144: WARN/System.err(4056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 09:26:34.144: WARN/System.err(4056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 09:26:34.144: WARN/System.err(4056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
03-03 09:26:34.144: WARN/System.err(4056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-03 09:26:34.144: WARN/System.err(4056):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I've logged the url returned included int the intent : 03-03 09:26:33.187: INFO/OAuthTwitter : url(4056): myapp://moreactivity?oauth_token=EAslQmKNyEfo1t8KgpFVsNk2WF3EDTxNmLkIpx2X0&oauth_verifier=F8GdO56ovRjKGnLNzp4LNPf6ASCJomOkXlJeKywhuM

Comment: Please format your code sections.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The community is more likely to help you out if you format code and logs in your question in a readable way. There's a comprehensive guide to formatting with Markdown at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Consider this fix a freebie, though :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in your logs.

```
03-03 09:26:34.140: WARN/System.err(4056): {"request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json","error":"Request token must be exchanged for an access token before use"}
```

After you get a request token and the user returns from allowing access on twitter.com you have to [exchange the request token for an access token](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#access-token).